# React react-tap-event-plugin firing event twice with mouse click

Tags: javascript, ios, events, reactjs

I'm attempting to use https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin for eliminating the 300ms delay on iphone tap events, but upon clicking my element with a mouse, the event is firing twice.  Here's my code:

In my main app.js file:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin({
    ignoreMouseThreshhold: 1000 //I've tried with and without this
});
```

In my component:

```
<th
    onTouchTap={ this.handleTap.bind(this); }
    onClick={ this.handleTap.bind(this); }>
```

The handleTap method is firing twice when clicking the element from a computer mouse.

Edit: After inspecting the events, it appears that a "mouseup" event is fired, directly followed by a "click" event.

Comment: Which version of react are you using?

Comment: 0.14.7 -- It seems to work if I remove the click handler altogether

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onTouchTap firing twice with material-ui dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363789/ontouchtap-firing-twice-with-material-ui-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `onTouchTap` do not use `onClick`.